# In TSQL, does the SET command must in it's own batch?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm facing a problem now. I use ruby and **SQLCMD** to generate some TSQL scripts. Now I want to check the syntax of the generated script. I use the following SQL:

```
SET PARSEONLY ON;
SELECT 888
SET PARSEONLY OFF;
```

I test it in SSMS, when you select these three statements as a whole batch, sql server will give me the result, which is 888. I don't want the actual result, I just want to test whether the syntax of my script is right. So I tried the following SQL:

```
SET PARSEONLY ON;
GO
SELECT 888
GO
SET PARSEONLY OFF;
GO
```

Now if I select all these statements as a whole batch, SQL Server will just tell me **Command(s) completed successfully**. So what I want to know is whether the **SET** command should in it's own batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yousui, No what you are doing is almost right; Read [here](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/adonet/t11228-syntax-check.aspx) for more info.
Just one thing: you cannot use SET PARSEONLY ON and SET PARSEONLY OFF in the same statement because the query would be executed and not parsed. 
So try this:

```
SET PARSEONLY ON
*-- YOUR QUERY*
GO
SET PARSEONLY OFF
```

Just remember that PARSEONLY only checks the syntax, not the objects, like tables etc. If you want to do object validation and checks use NOEXEC;

```
SET NOEXEC ON GO
*-- YOUR QUERY HERE* 
SET NOEXEC OFF
```